# Why did Microsoft choose a RESTful API over WebDAV for BLOB storage?

Tags: rest, webdav

Microsoft's new [Windows Live Application Based Storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305108.aspx) is a RESTful API.

More info is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305108.aspx).

Why did they choose not to support WebDAV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebDAV is for managing files on a remote server, but perhaps is not generic enough for what Microsoft was trying to accomplish.

There's also a lot of hype around REST lately and they are probably in competition with S3 from Amazon which offers a REST API.

It would have been good of them to provide their RESTful API as well as WebDAV.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has ADO.NET data service which provides RESTful API for data. 
Perhaps they have used the framework for the storage.

Answer (score -2):

Im been using WebDav on some other project like android and see all kind of scenario compare from REST Api.

Using WebDav, when you had multiple files like 5 thousand files or more and getting there value from the webdav server, open the file take time because of streaming or reading each of them, using REST Api in one content for all records in good format of json is faster than webdav.

Comment: and also dealing with large multiple files using WebDav is not advantage, very slow on syncing. like for example if you had 2 thousand files like ics or vcf, getting the value from server ics and vcf file and because it was blob, you are open the file and streamining then close, and because there are many files to open transfering records to your device, this will take long, compare using REST api, it will take you seconds not minutes or hrs.

Comment: I don't believe you understand WebDAV. What's the problem with big files, and how is it different in a "REST" API?

Comment: Sorry to say Big File my mistake, what i mean is large number of files, For example you had 5 thousand files and this are ics and vcf extension, getting there value to transfer into your device take a lot of time, unlike REST API JSON Response for those all ics and vcf content in one format to send take only seconds. In Summary it depend on your project if WebDav or REST API.

Comment: WebDAV is an extension to HTTP. Nobody stops you from having custom handlers that extend it.